# CSS - Justify-content not affecting the flexed items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So I'm working on a small tech challenge and using flexbox. I am having `display: flex;` set on the parent div and in the same css property I'm trying to use `justify-content` to `space-evenly`. However, it is simply having no effect.

My CSS:

```
.relatedFlex 
{
  display: flex;
  background-color: #fff;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

My HTML:

```
   <section class="relatedPost">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>Related post:</h2>
        <div class="relatedFlex">
            <div class="relatedSectionOne">
                <img class="photoWidth" src="assets/image-2.jpg" alt="Looking Stoic">
                <div>
                    <p>MAR 9, 2019</p>
                    <h3>Juno Tech Test</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente quidem hic natus?</p>
                    <button>Read More</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="relatedSectionTwo">
                <img class="photoWidth" src="assets/image-3.jpg" alt="Hands On Learning">
                <div>
                    <p>MAR 15, 2019</p>
                    <h3>Juno Tech Test</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente quidem hic natus?</p>
                    <button>Read More</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="relatedSectionThree">
                <img class="photoWidth" src="assets/image-3.jpg" alt="Hands On Learning">
                <div>
                    <p>MAR 15, 2019</p>
                    <h3>Juno Tech Test</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente quidem hic natus?</p>
                    <button>Read More</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

just give a width to your related sections

```css
.relatedFlex {
display: flex;
background-color: #fff;
justify-content: space-between;
}

.relatedSectionOne{
width:15vw;
}
```

```html
   <section class="relatedPost">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>Related post:</h2>
        <div class="relatedFlex">
            <div class="relatedSectionOne">
                <img class="photoWidth" src="assets/image-2.jpg" alt="Looking Stoic">
                <div>
                    <p>MAR 9, 2019</p>
                    <h3>Juno Tech Test</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente quidem hic natus?</p>
                    <button>Read More</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="relatedSectionOne">
                <img class="photoWidth" src="assets/image-3.jpg" alt="Hands On Learning">
                <div>
                    <p>MAR 15, 2019</p>
                    <h3>Juno Tech Test</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente quidem hic natus?</p>
                    <button>Read More</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="relatedSectionOne">
                <img class="photoWidth" src="assets/image-3.jpg" alt="Hands On Learning">
                <div>
                    <p>MAR 15, 2019</p>
                    <h3>Juno Tech Test</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente quidem hic natus?</p>
                    <button>Read More</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: That's the correct answer. Your divs are to wide because you didn't set a width. Adding width will solve this

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys! Still really new at this, So I've individually added widths to the related sections and it cures some of my problems but causes another. It shifts everything (the three sections) in the div down and creates a huge pseudo-top padding. All 3 items shift down 600+ pixels. So far haven't worked out why.

Comment: Quick edit - it is successfully spaced evenly however adjusting width on the individual related sections doesn't solve the above problem. I've tried stuff like calc(33% - the padding) But nothing gets rid of the ghost space unless I use an obscenely small width (like 10%).